# Existe alguma ferramenta que gere documentação similar a MSDN?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msdn, documentação

Existe algum programa que transforme a documentação do meu código (posso gerar o .xml) em páginas no estilo da MSDN? Ou em um formato wiki?