# Documentação em C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentação, mono

Gostaria de documentar uma api para C#, no estilo *javadoc*. Existe alguma forma de se decorar/comentar o código de forma que seja gerada documentação dos tipos e de seus membros automaticamente?

C# dá suporte nativo a isso, ou é necessário alguma ferramenta externa?

Comment: @bigown concordo com o fechamento da pergunta como estava - agora penso em [melhorá-la para que possa se encaixar no formato do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6211/fazer-uma-pergunta-melhor-que-foi-fechada?cb=1). Acredito que documentação XML automática seja útil para muita gente e que possa ser resolvida de uma forma única e direta [conforme suportado pela plataforma](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @Renan sua edição foi cirúrgica.

Comment: mas já deixou de ser "baseada em opniões"

Comment: Agora acho que é duplicata, deixa eu achar.

Comment: @bigown eu procurei uma pra marcar esta como duplicata e não achei - mas se houver uma é bom que a gente fica com um apontador pra resposta canônica.

Comment: @bigown seria essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/693/existe-alguma-ferramenta-que-gere-documentação-similar-a-msdn ?

Comment: @lemoce essa parece adequada.

Comment: @lemoce não, não tem nada a ver.

Comment: Achei essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78552/101 mas tem alguma mais específica ainda, tá difícil achar, mas eu sei que respondi. Acho até que tem dup de dup aí

Comment: @lemoce De qualquer forma... coloque comentários XML sobre seus tipos e membros. Experimenta escrever três barras (`///`) em cima de um método que tenha retorno e parâmetros, por exemplo. Depois compila o código com a opção `/doc` que o que Visual Studio gera um arquivo com a documentação no mesmo diretório que as DLL's.

Comment: @bigown existe outra tecnologia bastante utilizada pra isso, que não está em nenhum link desses que foi mencionado. Por que colocar como pendente a pergunta?

Comment: @lemoce está utilizando ASP.NET Core Web Api?

Comment: @Perozzo a versão inicial da pergunta perguntava qual a **melhor ferramenta**, o que fazia dela opiniosa. A versão atual é mais útil, mas é semelhante a perguntas já feitas antes. Se nenhuma pergunta semelhante feita antes tem a ferramenta que você tem em mente, você pode responder nelas.

Comment: @Renan As perguntas antes feitas, não fazem referência a uma API em C#.

Comment: @Perozzo responde lá então, inclusive eu mesclei as duas perguntas que já existiam.

Comment: @Renan acho que achei as duas melhores. Essa é relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29709/101

Comment: @Perozzo eu estou usando o Monodevelop, mas eu vou dar uma lida nessas respostas. Talvez eu utilize o doxygen para isso, mas ainda vou avaliar.